# $4$ women and $2$ men are being interviewed. Find the probability the women will be interviewed first.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics

My Calculations:

$$\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{3} = \frac 1 {15}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean the probability that all 4 women are interviewed before the two men?

Comment: @nrpeterson Yes.

Comment: The answer is correct. The reasoning is not explained, but it is reasonably clear what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the result is correct. And a more direct reasoning might be the following:

There're 6! permutations (orders) of the interviews, and 4!2! of them satisfy your limit that all four women come first. So $P=\frac{4!2!}{6!}=\frac{1}{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is fine.

**Variant 1:** The four women being interviewed first, is the same as the men being interview last, which is
$$\frac26\cdot\frac15=\frac1{15}$$
following the same reasoning.

**Variant 2:** There are $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to choose the positions of the $4$ women in the queue of length $6$. Only one is as desired, so the probability is 
$$\frac{1}{\binom{6}{4}}=\frac  1{15}$$
(Again, arguing with men instead of women works just as fine)

Comment: Your second solution doesn't seem correct (though the result is) to me. You are making the (correct in this problem, but implicit) assumption that every choice of the four positions has the same number of permutations associated with them. This reasoning is wrong when this is not the case. Your first variant is fine, because you are essentially using a permutation argument which is "at the lowest level" (and thus nothing can go wrong).

Comment: @ftfish I principally agree with your objection. It is the indistinguishableness of the men/women, that allows this simplification, maybe I should have remarked this.